# Backbone Model get attribute function returns last updated value

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

If there's an optional field in the server returned JSON top structure. Backbone Model seem to cache previously set value. Lets say i get a JSON like this

{
label: "test_label",
attr1: "test1",
attr2: "test2"
}

when I say @model.get("label") i get "test_label". So later on, if i get a JSON like this

{
attr1: "test1",
attr2: "test2"
}

i get "test_label" when i query for @model.get("label"). Is this a known issue in backbone.js? I do something like this to fetch

```
@modelXhr = @model.fetch
  success: (-> this.trigger('reset')).bind @model
```

I'm a beginner in javascript/coffeescript, What can i do so when i query for a field which doesn't exist in the latest returned model I won't get an older value? Appreciate your help

Comment: My model should look like the json atleast that's my goal, if json has label attribute model should, if not then the model shouldn't. But the way backbone behaves right now is that if there's a new attribute, it adds it and subsequent fetches will populate the attribute with the latest one that it got from the past, if it makes sense.

Comment: What is the question? Are you fetching more data from the server and expecting it to delete attributes that are not returned? If so, that is not how backbone works. if you want a fresh copy of everything, call `model.clear()` before setting new values

Answer (score 0):

You should either clear the model beforehand using `@model.clear()` or (in my opinion the better way) ensure that the data format for a specific model type does not change. Return `{ label: null, ... }`

You are then later on able to check for the existence of the label using `@model.get("label")?`

If you are not able to ensure data integrity throughout your requests, clear the model.